# Asymptotes and Definition of Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand how functions can have asymptotes. Consider the function $f(x) = (x+1)/(x+2)$ from $R$ to $R$. In this case, by the the definition of a function, $f(-2)$ must be defined since every element in the domain must map to something in the codomain, but it is not. I am very confused.

Comment: $f(2)=3/4$; did you mean $f(-2)$?  that's not defined since division by $0$ is not defined; the function is defined on $\mathbb R\setminus\{-2\}$

Comment: But the definition of a function I see is that it must be defined for every element in the domain, in this case $R$.

Comment: -2 is not in the domain.

Comment: It is specified that it is a function from $R$ to $R$, so $R$ is the domain and $-2$ is in$ R$.. Rosen Discrete Math 2.3 # 22.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly observed that $-2$ is not in the domain of this function. It is not a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

But sometimes maps like this are so called. This is a loose way of speaking and it is implied that the problematic points should be omitted from the domain. It is technically incorrect, but easier to say.

Comment: I have taken advanced math classes already and am taking a discrete math class for credit. It is very confusing going back and see how much you took for granted. Even proving $x^3$ is injective rigorously was confusing in the beginning.